# Get the current working directory of a azure webjob with powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-webjobs

I have created a powershell file which should download a .zip file:

```
$url = "https://volafile.io/get/GTw_OAH5W62w/t.zip"
$output = "%WEBROOT_PATH%\erp_tool_export.zip"

(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $output)
```

The script is executed without any errors but I can not find the .zip file using kudu explorer on my site.

There must be something wrong with the path where the file is put.

I checked the evn variables in kudu powershell cmd:

```
Get-Childitem env:
```

There is the variable 'WEBROOT_PATH' which I used above, but no file is at path:
wwwroot folder.

Actually I would like to put the zip file at the current working directory of the webjob, how can this be done?

Comment: try `$output = "$(Get-Location)\erp_tool_export.zip"`, should save to the current dir of the powershell, which most likely would be there...

Comment: Well you probably don't want to save there, because WebJobs get copied to a temp path and run from there. So the zip would be saved in a non-persistent place. Though you can turn off that behavior. See https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#webjob-working-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell uses a different syntax for environment variables. Change the line to:

```
$output = "$env:WEBROOT_PATH\erp_tool_export.zip"
```

Comment: I have just seen your comment to user 4c74... when after downloading I want to extract that zip file and move the files inside the zip`s folders to azure blob storage, then I should better use the webroot path instead of the working directory? Btw. thanks your path worked!

Comment: If you want to use current dir, you can, but you should use `is_in_place` in your [settings,job](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#settingsjobs-reference). This way, it will directly run from where you deploy it.